# Print line only if the upper line include specific word

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

We have the following file with hostnames and host ip's ( long file with 90-100 machines per linux machine )

`hosts.cluster.conf`

```
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker02.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.65"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker03.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.66"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker04.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "host_name" : "worker04.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.67"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker05.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.68"
```

we want to print all **host_name** lines only if the upper line before include the "**cluster_name**" word

expected results

```
"host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",

"host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",

"host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
```

Comment: `grep -B 1 'host_name' file | grep -A 1 'cluster_name' | grep 'host_name'`?

Comment: Is this a subset of something that was originally in JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '/cluster_name/{ cl=NR }/host_name/ && NR-1==cl' hosts.cluster.conf
```

- `/cluster_name/{ cl=NR }` - capturing the record number of `"cluster_name"` line
- `/host_name/` - on encountering `"host_name"` line
- `NR-1==cl` - ensuring that the current `"host_name"` record number `NR` is next after `"cluster_name"` record number (presented by `cl`)

---

The output:

```
"host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
"host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
"host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
```

---

In case if `host_name` appears as the 1st line, though I doubt about that in real case, use the following version:

```
awk '/cluster_name/{ cl=NR }/host_name/ && cl && NR-1==cl' hosts.cluster.conf
```

Comment: This will print out even `host_name` on first line.

Comment: @PesaThe, see my update, though your assumption is far from realistic structure of `hosts.cluster.conf`

Comment: True, it was just a nitpick. Anyway, nice edit :)

Answer (score 5):

```
sed '/host_name/!h;//!d;x;/cluster_name/!d;g' infile
```

will save each line that doesn't match `host_name` to the `h`old buffer and then `d`elete it; for each remaining line it will e`x`change buffers and, if the pattern space doesn't contain `cluster_name` it will delete it, else it will `g`et the original line back from the hold buffer and autoprint.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 awk '/cluster_name/ {p=1 ; next ;} 
 /host_name/ && p { print ; }
 {p=0}'
```

This basically remember line with `cluster_name`.
If `host_name` is found, without `cluster_name` before, it won't be printed.

Note that the whole awk code can be one-lined.

Comment: `{p=0}` will always reset the `p` flag to `0`. You probably forgot to use: `{p=1; next}`.

Comment: @PesaThe your are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$/='';

while(<>) {
 next unless (m/"cluster_name"/);
 chomp;

 foreach my $l (split /\n/) {
    print $l, "\n\n" if ($l =~ m/"host_name"/);
 };
};
```

In English: Reading the file a paragraph at a time (`$/='';`), skip paragraphs that don't contain the string `"cluster_name"`.  For those that do contain that string, iterate through each line of the paragraph and print lines containing `"host_name"`, with two newlines after each instance.

Example output:

```
$ ./extract-hosts.pl hosts.cluster.conf 
    "host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",

    "host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",

    "host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
```

Comment: anonymous downvoter: so what's wrong with this answer?  Leave a comment to explan the problem.  Given that the OP included `/perl` as one of the tags and this answer is the ONLY one that **exactly** reproduces the OP's requested output, is it just that you don't like perl?

Answer (score 1):

Well we have `sed` and `awk`, now time for GNU `grep`!

`cat infile | grep --after-context 1 cluster_name | grep host_name`

**Explanation**

The first command `cat` reads out the data into the pipe for processing. You can replace this segment with any command that outputs your source text to `stdout`.

The second command finds any line with "cluster_name" in it, and prints it and the following line. The intermediate output is this:

```
"cluster_name" : "hdp",
"host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
--
"cluster_name" : "hdp",
"host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
--
"cluster_name" : "hdp",
"host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
```

Then the final segment only prints the contents of the lines with "host_name" in them. Thus the final output is:

```
"host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
"host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
"host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
```

**Remarks**

1. Not every `grep` has the `--before-context parameter.` Make sure you are using GNU grep and you should be fine.
2. If this is language like JSON, you would be better off to learn and use a language appropriate parser like jmespath or `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE:"
cat $FILE

pl " Expected output:"
cat $E

pl " Results:"
cgrep -D -w '"href"' +w '"ip"' "cluster_name" $FILE |
grep '"host_name"'
```

produces:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker02.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.65"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker03.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.66"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker04.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "host_name" : "worker04.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.67"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker05.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.68"


  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/hosts/worker06.sys87.com",
  "Hosts" : 
    "host_name" : "worker06.sys87.com",
    "cluster_name" : "hdp",
    "ip" : "23.67.32.69"

-----
 Expected output:
"host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",

"host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",

"host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",

-----
 Results:
    "host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
    "host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
    "host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
    "host_name" : "worker06.sys87.com",
```

It first extracts all stanzas that contain "cluster_name". It does so by extracting stanzas that are regions (or windows: -w, +w) "href" .. "ip". From this subset, then a normal grep extracts the desired lines matching "host_name".

This scheme allows the lines "cluster_name" and "host_name" to appear anywhere in the stanza, even in different relative positions, such as in the additional stanza for "worker06".

Done on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
cgrep ATT cgrep 8.15
```

Some details for cgrep:

```
cgrep   shows context of matching patterns found in files (man)
Path    : ~/executable/cgrep
Version : 8.15
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Home    : http://sourceforge.net/projects/cgrep/ (doc)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

Another straightforward `sed`:

```
 sed -n '/host_name/ { x; /cluster_name/ { x; p; x }; x }; h' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another `sed` solution, that will perhaps be easier to understand than the others:

```
sed -n '/cluster_name/{n;/host_name/p}'
```

Here we just look for a line matching `cluster_name`, and if the next line matches `host_name`, we print it.

Answer (score 0):

Below  sed onliner command does the same.Tested its works fine

```
sed -n '/cluster_name/,+1p' hosts.cluster.conf | sed -n '/host_name/p'
```

output

```
  "host_name" : "worker02.sys87.com",
    "host_name" : "worker03.sys87.com",
    "host_name" : "worker05.sys87.com",
```